# Is it possible to take the Easy Rider Bus from Parkersburg (Marathon Gas Station) to downtown Parkersburg, WV?

Tags: public-transport, west-virginia

I'm taking Barons Bus to Parkersburg, West Virginia, and it drops off at a [Marathon Gas Station](https://maps.app.goo.gl/LcBszAiizZURBex5A). The problem that then presents itself is that this is far outside the Parkersburg city centre (if you can even call it that), and as far as I can tell there's no path from this place where I safely could walk but instead just roads. Which makes sense, given that it's a gas station. Still, this gas station is not my final destination, so I looked into ways to get around that isn't getting picked up by someone, and I found that Easy Rider Bus
seems to have a line that goes there called [Rayon](https://easyriderbus.com/routes-schedules/rayon/).

However, the map is really not that clear to me. There is a line going down towards where I think Marathon Gas Station is, but it's cut off on the map. Looking at [the map of all lines](https://easyriderbus.com/routes-schedules/), there's a dotted line going down to where I would think Marathon Gas Station is. I can't seem to find what the dotted line means. It does not seem to be what the [Rider's Guide](https://easyriderbus.com/riders-guide/) refers to as a "Deviation" as on the same map, deviations are shown as lines filled with white instead of the same colour as the border. These can be verified to be deviations based on [the map of the Jefferson Street Bus Route](https://easyriderbus.com/routes-schedules/jefferson-st/) where they are marked as such.

I can verify that the Rayon line does go to a place very close to Marathon Gas Station called "Edgelawn" based on the table next to the map, but assuming this refers to the Edgelawn Street, it's still a 10 minute walk on roads that lack any pavement as far as I can tell based on Google Maps. And even if I were to make that potentially dangerous walk, I don't know exactly where the bus would pick up.

So, with all that in mind, would it within reason be possible to take the Easy Rider Bus from the Marathon Gas Station to downtown Parkersburg, West Virginia?

Comment: My European bus experience makes me think that a dotted section of a bus line is one that is only served at specific times. But I don't think this is the thing here

Comment: I notice that is the Greyhound Bus Stop too so you can't be the only person who needs to continue their journey.

Comment: I wasn't able to find anything obviously looking like a bus _stop_ but Google Street View did happen to catch a photo of [a bus going down Camden Ave not too far north of Edgelawn St](https://maps.app.goo.gl/a16SRHAHAJYS63fm8), so it did in fact go, well, somewhere around there, as recently as August 2023.